# looping through response object angular

Tags: c#, arrays, angular, typescript, loops

I am trying to iterate through an array which hold some values which i want to present to the user. I am having some difficulty extracting these values with angular. Im not sure what i am doing wrong. I am getting a response so i know the request is coming back however i cannot seem to access or loop through the parts of the array.

c# code:

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class MapController : ApiController
{
    Map[] map = new Map[]
    {
        new Map { Map_Data_ID = 122, County = "West Yorkshire", Color = "#d45faa"},
        new Map { Map_Data_ID = 122, County = "West Yorkshire", Color = "#d45faa"},
    };

    public IEnumerable<Map> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return map;
    }
}
```

Angular:

```
test: Array<{id: Number, value: string, color: string}> = [];

getMapData() {     
       this._interactiveMapService.getMapData()
          .subscribe(
              data => {
                  var arr = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({type: key, value: data[key]}));
                  for(var i; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    this.test.push({id: i.Map_Data_ID, value: i.County, color: i.Color});
                  }
              })
    }
```

[image]

This is what i want to attach the response data too

Example:

```
 this.dataSource = {
      chart: {
        caption: "Depot Locations",
        subcaption: "United Kingdom (Counties)",
        numbersuffix: "%",
        includevalueinlabels: "1",
        labelsepchar: ": ",
        entityFillHoverColor: "#FFF000",
        theme: "fint",
      },   
      // Source data as JSON --> id represents counties of england.
      data: [
        {
          id: "126",
          value: "Anglesey",       
          color: "#d45faa"
        },
        {
          id: "108",
          value: "Argyl & Bute",          
          color: "#d45faa"
        }
      ]
    }
```

example response from server:

```
[
    {
        "Map_Data_ID": 122,
        "County": "West Yorkshire",
        "Color": "#d45faa"
    },
    {
        "Map_Data_ID": 167,
        "County": "Wiltshire",
        "Color": "#d45faa"
    }
]
```

Comment: What does the response look like in angular i.e what does `console.log(data)` return?

Comment: `i` in `this.test.push({id: i.Map_Data_ID, value: i.County, color: i.Color})`  is a loop control variable. That means it will have values: 0, 1, 2.... It is not a Object.

Comment: when i try to access parts of the response like data.Color i get no intelisense suggestions. i need to access each value within the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the response is of the following format:

```
data =  [ { "Map_Data_ID": 122, "County": "West Yorkshire", "Color": "#d45faa" }, { "Map_Data_ID": 167, "County": "Wiltshire", "Color": "#d45faa" } ];
```

you may do so using

```
.subscribe(data => {
  this.data.forEach(e => {
    this.test.push({
      id: e.Map_Data_ID,
      value: e.County,
      color: e.Color
    })
  })
});
```

---

Since we are in the *world* of typescript we can define a class to hold this data and make our lives more easier.

```
export class CountryDetails {
  constructor(
    private id: number,
    private value: string,
    private color: string
  ) {}
}
```

now using the newly created class:

```
.subscribe(data => {
  this.data.forEach(e => {
    this.test.push(new CountryDetails(e.Map_Data_ID, e.County, e.Color));
  })
});
```

Comment: i get this [
    {
        "Map_Data_ID": 122,
        "County": "West Yorkshire",
        "Color": "#d45faa"
    },
    {
        "Map_Data_ID": 167,
        "County": "Wiltshire",
        "Color": "#d45faa"
    }
]

Comment: The problem i think is that the collection has no name attached to it

Comment: Okay.. so what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: possibly this data = [
    {
        "Map_Data_ID": 122,
        "County": "West Yorkshire",
        "Color": "#d45faa"
    },
    {
        "Map_Data_ID": 167,
        "County": "Wiltshire",
        "Color": "#d45faa"
    }
]

Comment: i mean the data is somewhat irrelevant i am more interested in lopping through the contents and assigning the values to my array. i want to access the elements like data.color

Comment: Maybe I've missed something but what you just pinged is exactly the same response as the first comment?

Comment: What i get back is what i expect to be returned. The problem i am having is looping through that array. That is where the issue lies.

Comment: I've made an edit, still feel we aren't on the same page. Can you provide a sample input with expected output?

Comment: okay i think it has something to do with how data is being instantiated. at the moment it is data:object; which is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry bud - that doesn't help. Using the above answer, we are looping through the `data` response and assigning the respective fields from it to be pushed onto the `test` array..

Comment: The problem is that it is never being pushed to that array. I get this error Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Object'. I added a bit more detail in my first post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203769/discussion-between-nicholas-k-and-ashley-g).